# Java Program cannot read more more than 64116 files and throws an exception with no stacktrace

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu-14.04, indexoutofboundsexception, printstacktrace

I have fairly new to JAVA (as it looks like). Using eclipse I wrote a program to read around 150k files and then I am printing the content of each file to console.

Interestingly (at least to me), after reading 64116 files the program throws a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException without any StackTrace. I tried to catch the exception manually and figure out the cause of exception but it returns null.
Also, I tried to call

```
   System.gc()
```

to get the memory free, in case it is overloaded with objects but no luck.
[image]

I am using
-64Bit 
-16GB RAM
-Core-i7 - 3.60GHz
-Ubuntu 14.04
-Eclipse IDE
-OpenJDK-7

Here is the code I am running -

```
  try {
        for(File file : fileList){
            String fileName = file.getPath();
            ExtractorFromFile extr = new ExtractorFromFile();
            DemoClass obj = extr.extract(fileName);
            Map<String, Integer> wordListforCurrent = obj.uniqueWordList();
            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : wordListforCurrent.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                Integer value = entry.getValue();
                if( !universalWordList.containsKey( entry.getKey() ) ){
                    universalWordList.put(key, 1);
                }
                else {
                    Integer newVal = universalWordList.get(key);
                    newVal++;
                    universalWordList.put(key, newVal);
                }
            }
            count ++;

            if(count == 50000){
                System.gc();
                //break;
            }
        }           
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Count:" +count);
        System.out.println(e.getCause());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is the extract() method if you wanna have a look -

```
    public Test extract(String fileName) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    Test test = new Test();

    try {
        // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
        FileReader fileReader = 
            new FileReader(fileName);

        // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
            new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println(line);
            //some String processing here
        }

        // Always close files.
        bufferedReader.close();         
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Unable to open file '" + 
            fileName + "'");                
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Error reading file '" 
            + fileName + "'");                  
        // Or we could just do this: 
        // ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return test;
}
```

Can anyone let me know what am I doing wrong? How do I get to read any number of text files using JAVA without any error or exception? I have never edited any JVM configuration file. So if it comes to edit JVM configuration I will appreciate something close to a step by step suggestion.

Thanks for you time everyone.

Comment: You're running out of [file handles](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36841/why-is-number-of-open-files-limited-in-linux).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. How do I not get running out file handles?

Comment: The implementation of `extract()`, which you didn't show, is not closing the file before returning.

Comment: I have tried setting the ulimit to 1000000, but it does not work @MikeSamuel

Comment: Remove the catching of any unchecked exceptions, like where you just catch Exception in general. Let it fail and print a stack trace with line information.

Comment: NOTE: you can check the #/open files with [lsof](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof), or looking at `/proc/sys/fs/file-nr`.  If the #.files increases by 1000's when you run your program, that's the culprit.  Otherwise, perhaps you might try a different Java version or JRE.